# Fetch only happens once or if I open developer tools

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, fetch-api, developer-tools

I'm working on a website that should fecth some reports on mongoDB and place markers on a map according to the location of those reports.
The issue is that: that only happens once when I open the website (on local, sometimes online it doesn't happen at all), and for the fetch to happen I noticed I have to open developer tools. If I do, the markers will appear.
I don't understand what is causing this issue, but after some digging online I have come to a few hypothesis:

- console.log - I've removed them all by now
- cache - I installed nocache

The issue still resides. Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

fetch

```
    const [markers, setMarkers] = useState<Array<GeoReport>>([]);
    const fetchReports = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND + '/api/report');
        const json = await response.json();
        json.forEach((report: GeoReport) => {
            markers.push({
                id: report.id,
                lat: report.lat,
                lng: report.lng,
                adress: report.adress,
                placeId: report.placeId,
                surveys: report.surveys,
                fileName: report.fileName,
                imgName: report.imgName
            });
        });
        setMarkers([...markers]);
        dispatch.setMap(
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
            markers.reduce((acc: any, curr: any) => {
                (acc[curr.adress] = acc[curr.adress] || []).push(curr);
                return acc;
            }, {} as { [key: string]: GeoReport[] }),
        );
        
    };
```

server

```
import express from 'express';
import * as Colors from 'colors.ts';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import nocache from 'nocache';

import { connectDB } from './database/db';
import { errorHandler } from './middleware/errorMiddleware';
import { FRONTEND_URL, PORT } from './utils/config';
import reportRoutes from './routes/reportRoutes';
import driveRoutes from './routes/driveRoutes';
import driveImageRoutes from './routes/driveImageRoutes';
// Apply Colors to consoleLogs
Colors.colors('', '');

// Connection to DB
export const db = async (): Promise<void> => {
    await connectDB();
};

void db();

const app = express();
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true,
    })
);
app.use(nocache());
app.set('etag', false);

const allowedOrigins = FRONTEND_URL;

// const options: cors.CorsOptions = {
//     origin: allowedOrigins,
// };

app.use(
    cors({
        origin: allowedOrigins,
    })
);
app.use(express.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    //console.log(req.path, req.method);
    next();
});

app.use('/api/report', reportRoutes);
app.use('/api/drive', driveRoutes);
app.use('/api/driveimage', driveImageRoutes);

app.use(errorHandler);

app.listen(PORT, () =>
    console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`.green.underline.bold)
);
```

reportRoutes

```
import express from 'express';

import {
    getAllreportsHandler,
    createreportHandler,
    getreportHandler,
} from '../controllers/reportController';
const reportRoutes = express.Router();

reportRoutes.route('/').get(getAllreportsHandler).post(createreportHandler);
reportRoutes.route('/:id').get(getreportHandler);

export default reportRoutes;
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you are using a React frontend.
A potential problem is in your use of markers list, because you are directily modifying the state

```
const [markers, setMarkers] = useState<Array<GeoReport>>([]);
```

You are modifying markers with `markers.push(...)` then you use `setMarkers([...markers]);`
You should use something like:

```
        const newMarkers = json.map((report: GeoReport) => ({
                id: report.id,
                lat: report.lat,
                lng: report.lng,
                adress: report.adress,
                placeId: report.placeId,
                surveys: report.surveys,
                fileName: report.fileName,
                imgName: report.imgName
            })
        );
        setMarkers(newMarkers);
```

Here a good explanation [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40309023/829300)

Comment: Thank you for your input @Taymer. I've tried it but nothing appears on the map using that solution. I'll study it a bit since I'm also a newbie and didn't do this part of the code